# JavaFX jar doesnt read .properties file

Tags: javafx, properties-file

I have developed a javafx application that reads the database configuration properties from a ".properties file".When i run the app in eclipse everything works fine.The problem is when running the app from the generated executable jar,it throws me a NullPointerException because it cant read the ".properties file".
The code is :

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("resources/META-INF/db/db.properties");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(fis);
```

I searched about this and i saw some examples of using InputStream :

```
Properties pp = new Properties();
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("errors.properties");
pp.load(is);
```

But still doesnt work.Any idea?**strong text**

Comment: You probably need to create a folder that you always have with you `Jar`. The folder name should be `resources`. This folder should have a folder named `META-INF`. `META-INF` should have a folder named `db`. Finally, `db` should have the `db.properties` file in it.

Comment: Write up an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a folder that you always have with you `Jar`. The folder name should be `resources`. This folder should have a folder named `META-INF`. `META-INF` should have a folder named `db`. Finally, `db` should have the `db.properties` file in it.

Comment: Well this was what i had done .But then i found that i should specify the folder as a source folder in order to be included in the jar

Comment: Yep, if you want it to be packaged inside the `jar`. If you didn't do that, you could create this folder and put it in the same folder as the `jar` and it should work.